# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined whenever I try to fetch a user by ID

Tags: angular, typescript, https, undefined

I am trying to search a user by ID but I can not.
Every time I call the function to fetch the user, it brings the user empty and I can't think of a resolution for this problem of mine.

My function:

```
getCandidate(candidate: Candidate) {
    this.candidateService.getCandidateById(candidate.id).subscribe( resp => {
      this.dataCandidate = resp;
    })
  }
```

In the function, I'm calling candidate.id but it returns error because the candidate is empty

My model:

```
export class Candidate {
    id: number;
    full_name: string;
    cpf: string;
    rg: number;
    birth_date: string;
    phone: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

My GET:

```
const apiUrl = 'https://delineaapi.herokuapp.com:443/candidate/';
getCandidateById(id: number): Observable<Candidate> {
    const url = `${apiUrl}${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Candidate>(url)
  }
```

If you type `console.log (candidate)` response comes empty

I have another function that returns a list of users, and this one is working perfectly.

Comment: @Leticia_Fatima
where you are initializing your Candidate class and please include your html code too

Comment: How do you call `getCandidate()`? and how do you pass candidate?

Comment: Well, the problem is in code you haven't posted. You are clearly passing an undefined reference to candidate in your call.

Comment: inside `getCandidate ` function if you do console `candidate` you are getting empty response, right ? It means wherever you are calling this function and passing `candidate`, issue is there. Can you please update that code too ?